# swift 3 how to add a button that refresh location and zoom at my location map kit

Tags: ios, mapkit, swift3, xcode8

please i need to find a way to add a button that refresh my location and zoom.I've tried everything, this is my code.

[map code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2R7y.png)

Comment: Please post relevant code here

Answer (score -1):

Add this to `viewDidLoad()` to show your users location:

```
self.map.showUserLocation = true
```

and in your `didUpdateLocations`, replace:

```
self.map.showUserLocation = true
```

with:

```
self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

to centre the map the the users current location.

Comment: I know this thing,but i don't know to use this function with a button.